# Discord.js Cache message on messageDelete/Update

Tags: javascript, caching, discord.js

I have a messageDelete and MessageUpdate event but when the messages arent cached it gives an error, can i cache the message inside of the messageDelete/Update, I have tried

`message.channels.cache.get(message.channel.id).message.cache.get(message.id)`

but it still gives the error

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')`

with messages sent before the bot was started

Answer (score 1):

```js
<Channel>.messages.fetch(messageID)
```

```js
message.channels.cache.get(message.channel.id).messages.cache.get(message.id)
```

You need to put s in messages

Comment: still the same error

Comment: because your using guildchannel, use `message.channel.messages.fetch()`

Comment: so `message.channel.messages.fetch(message.id)` ? if so that returns `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')` and `Unknown Message`

Comment: console.log(message) and share the result in your console

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZjBMCaA2